# Twice linear C#

Tags: c#

Consider a sequence u where u is defined as follows:

The number u(0) = 1 is the first one in u.
For each x in u, then y = 2 * x + 1 and z = 3 * x + 1 must be in u too.
There are no other numbers in u.
Ex: u = [1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 13, 15, 19, 21, 22, 27, ...]

1 gives 3 and 4, then 3 gives 7 and 10, 4 gives 9 and 13, then 7 gives 15 and 22 and so on...

Example:
test(10) should return 22

I have written several versions of my code, but I cannot pass all the tests. What do you think this may be connected with?

```
public int test(int n)
{
    List<int> result = new List<int>(new int[] { 1 });
    List<int> arr = new List<int>(new int[] { 1 });
    List<int> arr2 = new List<int>();
    int i = 0;
    while (Math.Pow(2, i++) < n)
    {
        arr2.Clear();
        arr2.AddRange(arr.Select(s => 2 * s + 1));
        arr2.AddRange(arr.Select(s => 3 * s + 1));
        arr.Clear();
        arr.AddRange(arr2.Distinct());
        result.AddRange(arr.OrderBy(s=>s));

    }
    return result.Distinct().OrderBy(s => s).ToList()[n];
}
```

I'm not interested in someone’s finished code, I’m interested in why I get an error and how, using my approach, I can get the right solution.

Comment: What test is it not passing?

Comment: As per your code test(10) returns 22 which is expected. Could you please share which test case is not passing.

Comment: I’m trying to complete the task at https://www.codewars.com/kata/twice-linear/train/csharp, unfortunately I can’t give you a test, only this:
Test failed   Expected: 335031   But was: 335187
Test failed   Expected: 3355   But was: 3358

Comment: `3355` is the result of `test(575)`. You're using 3 `List<int>` when you need just one (`result`). The loop is `int i = 0; while (n > i) { ... i += 1; }`. You're using two `Select()` calls when you need none. You just have to return `result[n]`.

Comment: ... in case distinct numbers are required, otherwise `3355` is the result of `test(500);`. The other conditions are the same.

Comment: I use 3 List because
result - used to store results
arr - I use to store the elements that appeared in the previous step
arr1 - the elements that I received in the current step.
Number 3358 - Five Hundredth Element.
Before that, I used one array, it worked, but because of the same error, I rewrote the code to the current

Comment: So, distinct numbers are required and the `n` value is the one I mentioned in the second comment. You **have** to use just one List, increase `i` or *loop it* `while (n > i)` , use `...OrderBy(...).Distinct();`, in this order. In the end, you have to `return result[n];`. Do not use `Select()` at any point, just `result.Add(...)` (twice).

Comment: **But** a `List<int>` is only a partially acceptable solution. You should use a `HashTable` (or a similar collection).

Comment: We cannot crop to n, since we must sort the elements, after n the element may be smaller, and then we will get an incorrect answer.
_As far as I understand_

Comment: [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/70Ae1U). Note that this is not exactly an acceptable solution. A `Distinct()` call per iteration is not good at all. The List shouldn't be ordered using LINQ. Fortunately, we have many different collections in .Net...

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do something with your option. At the moment, he also does not pass  the Execution Timed Out test (12000 ms)

Comment: That's why I said that a `Distinct()` call + `OrderBy()` per iteration is not an acceptable solution :)

Comment: @Jimi A list is a perfect acceptable solution, you just have to use it with the less known function `var searchIndex = list.BinarySearch(value)` and the magic method `if(searchIndex < 0) list.Insert(~searchIndex, value)`.

Comment: @Oliver Of course, that would work, too. The *non acceptable solution* is the use of any LINQ's functions in the iteration (I tried *not* to give a real solution, here, just a suggestion that only one collection is actually required and LINQ should be avoided). Anyway, this is how the code could look like with your suggestion: [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9Mhrcx),

Comment: @Oliver  The OP may appreciate the difference in execution time. I think it can be further improved.

Comment: Thank you, with the help of BinaraSarch I was able to pass all the tests.
My decision https://dotnetfiddle.net/4xjTwB

Comment: You don't need the `var newItem` assignement and, most of all, you don't need this: `result.OrderBy(s=>s).ToList()[n];` (no LINQ)

Comment: Taking the return value from `BinarySearch()` as value for the `Insert()` statement already ensures that the values are sorted. So an `.OrderBy()` is not necessary.

Comment: Just implemented it myself. Here is [my solution](https://www.codewars.com/kata/reviews/56726d3ce3659e3f8a00001f/groups/5e1eced253759a0001a34e16).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IEnumerable this way:

```cs
private static IEnumerable<int> seq() {
    var pending = new List<int>();
    var buffer = new List<int>();
    buffer.Add(1);
    pending.Add(1);

    while (true) {
        var batch = new List<int>();
        foreach (var n in buffer.Distinct())
        {
            batch.Add(2 * n + 1);
            batch.Add(3 * n + 1);
        }
        buffer.Clear();
        var batchMin = batch.Min();
        var readyToReturn = pending
            .Where(x => x <= batchMin)
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(x => x)
            .ToList();
        if (readyToReturn.Count > 0) {
            foreach(var x in readyToReturn)
                yield return x;
            pending.RemoveAll(x => readyToReturn.Contains(x));
            batch.RemoveAll(x => readyToReturn.Contains(x));
        }
        pending.AddRange(batch);
        buffer.AddRange(batch);
    }
}
```

Then you can call:

```cs
var result = seq().Skip(n).First();
```

I got these results:

```
OK    n: 0 expected: 1 got: 1
OK    n: 1 expected: 3 got: 3
OK    n: 2 expected: 4 got: 4
OK    n: 3 expected: 7 got: 7
OK    n: 4 expected: 9 got: 9
OK    n: 5 expected: 10 got: 10
OK    n: 6 expected: 13 got: 13
OK    n: 7 expected: 15 got: 15
OK    n: 8 expected: 19 got: 19
OK    n: 9 expected: 21 got: 21
OK    n: 10 expected: 22 got: 22
OK    n: 11 expected: 27 got: 27
OK    n: 20 expected: 57 got: 57
OK    n: 30 expected: 91 got: 91
OK    n: 50 expected: 175 got: 175
```

Comment: Test Failed: 57  But was:  55
( Sample tests: 10->22
20->57
30->91
50->175)

Comment: I see. Let me check.